# Long decimal numbers in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite

Required to store in a SQLite database the long decimal numbers. 12 signs - integer part, and 8 - in decimal, like that - '123456789012,12345678' (positive numbers only)

```
drop table if exists table1;

CREATE TABLE table1 (
 a INTEGER,
 b DECIMAL(20,8)
); 

INSERT INTO table1 select 1, 123456789012.12345678;

select * from table1;
```

Query result:

```
RecNo a                     b 
----- - --------------------- 
    1 1 123456789012.12345900
```

As we can see, it is rounding off the last digits in the decimal part. How can I get accurate result without rounding?

Comment: Please be aware that  `DECIMAL(20,8)` does not mean anything for SQLite except to give the column a numeric *affinity*, in particular, `(20,8)` makes no difference. See [DataTypes in SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html) for more information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQLite stores `numeric` (decimal) data types [up to 8 bytes](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html). But that is not sufficient to store your number including decimal places.

You could use `blob` to store it or `text`.

Comment: Wow, that's delusive. Why does sqlite allow defining 20 digits precision when it can only store 15? That's like *you can define a VarChar(1000) but we only store up to 500*

Comment: Well, it is sql LITE.